# Passing data Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, segue

I have TableView like this

[image]

and I want to pass data through segue different for every cell.

I have this code for every cell but I want different URL for each cell.

```
   var joj:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://88.212.10.27:81/streams/joj.m3u8")
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: joj)

    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
```

like in obj c - isEqualToString "Markíza"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to override prepareForSegue method where you will be able to access your next view controller properties.

for example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      var nextViewController : NextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as NextViewController

      var indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow() //get index of data for selected row      

      nextViewController.url = self.urlsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) // get data by index and pass it to second view controller
    }
}
```

Code in the nextView controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var joj:NSURL = NSURL(self.url) //this url is a property of your view controller which you use pass data between view controllers using prepareForSegueMethod
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: joj)

moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()
self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
}
```

Comment: i know this. All I want is how to do that for (example) Markiza (cell from picture) is link 1 a and for Jednotka is link 2

Comment: You need to store array of urls where each url stored at the index of appropriate cell

Comment: Can u make me example because I dont have idea how.

Comment: Ok. Can you show how do you store the data of your cells?

Comment: var programy = [Program]()   -   self.programy = [Program(name: "Markíza")]

Comment: You can add additional property for Program to store url. and then get it in prepareforsegue like self.urlsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).url. Of cause you need to cast object from array to Program before getting url

Comment: and how to store URL? or can u make me example how would u do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63351/discussion-between-patffo-and-sergey-pekar).